# Order by in foreach

Tags: php, wpdb, post-meta

hello im getting post_id by using wpdb after that i wanna show postmeta(sd_l2) order by their value

i uses this codes

```
global $wpdb

$top5_ov_performance = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT post_id FROM ".$wpdb->prefix."postmeta WHERE meta_key = 'sd_type' AND meta_value = 'desktop'");
    foreach ($top5_ov_performance as $ov_perforamnce) {
        $new_number = ($ov_perforamnce->meta_value / $mother_number) * 100;
            echo '<div class="box">';
            echo '<div style="width: '.$new_number.'%" class="fill">';
            echo '<div class="fill-badge">'.get_the_title($ov_perforamnce->post_id).'</div>';
            echo '</div>';
            echo '<div class="empty">';
            echo '<div class="empty-badge">'.get_post_meta($ov_perforamnce->post_id,'sd_l2',true).'</div>';
            echo '</div>';
            echo '</div>';
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do is pass the field you want to order by in your SQL:

```
ORDER BY post_id DESC
```

This example will get the post_ids out with the highest first e.g. 99, 98, 97

OR

```
ORDER BY post_id ASC
```

will do it: 1, 2, 3 and so on.

Alternativly if you want to group the results by the meta_value:

```
GROUP BY meta_value
```

Comment: yeah know , i need to get sd_l2 postmeta order by value

Comment: you should just be able to replace post_id with meta_value

Comment: or do you want to group them by the meta_value?

Comment: okay but how ??

Comment: I have updated the answer with the group by, although I'm not sure this is the result you want to achieve.